# How to bridge global app state to model view (using @ObservedObject)?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I have a centralized app state architecture (similar to Redux). This app state class is of type ObservableObject and bound to the SwiftUI view classes directly using @EnvironmentObject.

The above works well for small apps. But as the view hierarchy becomes more and more complex, performance issues start to kick in. The reason is, that ObservableObject fires an update to each view that has subscribed even though the view may only need one single property.

My idea to solve this problem is to put a model view between the global app state and the view. The model view should have a subset of properties of the global app state, the ones used by a specific view. It should subscribe to the global app state and receive notification for every change. But the model view itself should only trigger an update to the view for a change of the subset of the global app state.

So I would have to bridge between two observable objects (the global app state and the model view). How can this be done?

Here's a sketch:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var propertyA: Int
  @Published var propertyB: Int
}

class ModelView: ObservableObject {
  @Published var propertyA: Int
}

struct DemoView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var modelView: ModelView

  var body: some View {
    Text("Property A has value \($modelView.propertyA)")
  }
}
```

Comment: The View in real world application is some composition of lot of different Views. SwiftUI will "update" ONLY Views which depend on your model and ONLY if the value in model changed. And that is exactly what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach

```
class ModelView: ObservableObject {
    @Published var propertyA: Int = 0

    private var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(global: AppState) {
        global.$propertyA
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.propertyA, on: self)
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will test it and report back.

Comment: When I'm thinking again about the above proposed solution, I'm not sure whether it will solve the main problem: the global state will also trigger an update of propertyA even if only propertyB is changed. The "assign" will then store an unchanged value of propertyA to the model view's own propertyA which will trigger an update of the view.    Is this right?

Comment: No, this is explicit subscriber to one property publisher.

Comment: Excellent. One more question: do you know whether the Combine framework passes those objects by reference? I'm asking because if propertyA would be a large array, I wouldn't want to have a real copy of it in the view model because of memory concerns.

Comment: Swift explicitly uses copy-on-write only for dictionaries/collections. For other types the documentation mentions that you can implement it yourself.

Comment: @G.Marc "the global state will also trigger an update of propertyA even if only propertyB is changed" is not true.

Comment: @user3441734: This statement relates to class AppState and is the reason why I want a specific view model to only pick a selection of properties used in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The "bridge" you mentioned is often referred to as *Derived State*.

Here's an approach to implement a redux `Connect` component. It re-renders when the derived state changes...

```swift
public typealias StateSelector<State, SubState> = (State) -> SubState

public struct Connect<State, SubState: Equatable, Content: View>: View {

  // MARK: Public
  public var store: Store<State>
  public var selector: StateSelector<State, SubState>
  public var content: (SubState) -> Content

  public init(
    store: Store<State>,
    selector: @escaping StateSelector<State, SubState>,
    content: @escaping (SubState) -> Content)
  {
    self.store = store
    self.selector = selector
    self.content = content
  }

  public var body: some View {
    Group {
      (state ?? selector(store.state)).map(content)
    }.onReceive(store.uniqueSubStatePublisher(selector)) { state in
      self.state = state
    }
  }

  // MARK: Private
  @SwiftUI.State private var state: SubState?
}
```

To use it, you pass in the store and the "selector" which transform the application state to the derived state:

```
struct MyView: View {
  var index: Int

  // Define your derived state
  struct MyDerivedState: Equatable {
    var age: Int
    var name: String
  }

  // Inject your store
  @EnvironmentObject var store: AppStore

  // Connect to the store
  var body: some View {
    Connect(store: store, selector: selector, content: body)
  }

  // Render something using the selected state
  private func body(_ state: MyDerivedState) -> some View {
    Text("Hello \(state.name)!")
  }

  // Setup a state selector
  private func selector(_ state: AppState) -> MyDerivedState {
    .init(age: state.age, name: state.names[index])
  }
}
```

you can see the full implementation [here](https://github.com/gilbox/Cloe)